# Express virtual path prefix not working with angular 6 app

Tags: node.js, express, angular6, static-files, virtual-path

I'm hosting my angular 6 app with express static

```
app.use(express.static('/', __dirname +'/client/angular'));
```

The problem came when i tried to add another page to my server as a landing page. So i specified a mounth path '/app' to my angular app.

```
app.use(express.static('/app', __dirname +'/client/angular'));
```

This is not working! When i run the server this came out

> GET /app/ 304 4.294 ms - -
>
> GET /inline.bundle.js/ 404 1.065 ms - 15
>
> GET /polyfills.bundle.js/ 404 0.581 ms - 15
>
> GET /styles.bundle.js/ 404 2.195 ms - 15
>
> GET /vendor.bundle.js/ 404 2.119 ms - 15
>
> GET /main.bundle.js/ 404 1.830 ms - 15
>
> GET /favicon.ico 404 0.474 ms - 15

I managed the problem hosting the new webpage in a virtual path '/home' and keep my angular app hosted in the root path by default.

```
app.use('/home', express.static(__dirname +'/client/landing'));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname +'/client/angular'));
```

But these are not the routes i need so, does anybody know how to mount an angular app on express virtual path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a little bit more, i found out that I have to modify the index.html file of my angular app in the dist folder generated after run ng build. The problem was that the base href was "/", so when it needed the js files it didn't find them. So, all we have to do is change it, with the same path as it was mounted in the server

```
  <base href="/app">
```